# VS DataBreakpoints: difference between C and C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, breakpoints

when you set a databreakpoint in MSVS, then you put in the address and the number of bytes and finally it lets you choose betwenn "C" and "C++".

this last part i dont know what it is about? what is the difference of picking C and C++ in this situation?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only matters if you use an expression instead of entering the address directly.  Parsing rules for 'C' expressions are different from those for C++.  Can't think of a great example beyond a C++ member expression like "&this->member".  The debugger can't figure it out for itself, mixing 'C' and C++ code in one process is quite permissible.

Comment: How about bits like `A<5> B()` ?